# What is Config.Eager_load and how do I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to run a `rails db migrate` command, and its worked on many apps with the same setup as this one, but for whatever reason I am getting the following error:

```
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
    * development - set it to false
    * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
    * production - set it to true
```

But here's the thing. All of those are set correctly. I've even tried setting them incorrectly running it, and setting them correct again. I've restarted my computer, my app. Everything. I can't find a good explanation of what `config.eagar_load` even really is either. What is this thing? Why is it messing up my app? How do I even troubleshoot it?

Answer in part: I was using `rails db migrate` and should have been using `rails db:migrate` so that fixed the problem, but I would still like to know what config.eager_load is, and what it does.

Comment: What version of rails do use?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I recommend you [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/improving-the-performance-of-your-rails-app-with-eager-loading--cms-25018) great post.

Comment: How does it help? Question is about config, not Active Record.